# Ruby PCAP Reading a complete capture file

Tags: ruby, pcap

I am using Ruby to process some PCAP files. I need to read a complete file and analyze each pcaket.

```
require 'pcap'

inFile = Pcap::Capture.open_offline("1.pcap")

inFile.loop(-1) do |pkt|
#Process packet.
end
```

Above code does not exit after reading all the packets. According to the Ruby pcap documentation 'A negative count processes packets forever or until EOF is reached'. What can be the problem here.

Comment: I assume the `do` missing from your sample program wasn't the problem, so I just edited it in there for you. Once that bug is fixed, the dump I used worked just fine. So I assume the problem depends upon the specific dump in question. In that case, you may need to contact libpcap developers to see if they can spot a problem with your dump file, but a corrupted dump would be my first guess.

Comment: Which PCAP library are you using? Have you looked at any of the alternative gems? http://rubygems.org/search?query=pcap

Comment: @sarnold: That would be a nice answer

Comment: @andomar, I'm uneasy about posting vague guesses as _answers_ -- if @Indika reports the dump file was too invalid to parse, I'll happily move it to an answer :) but in the meantime I'm not convinced I'm right.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments and sorry about the mistake in the program. I tried the PCAP file at  [link] http://wiki.wireshark.org/SampleCaptures?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=SIP_CALL_RTP_G711. I tried several Capture files at Wireshark sample captures. But got the same result. I am using gem pcap (0.7.3) with Ruby 1.9.2.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using a variation of the below a lot for ad-hoc packet analysis.  Works for me.  Ruby 1.9.3-p125, pcaprub 0.11.2.

```
#!/opt/local/bin/ruby1.9
require 'pcaprub'

fn = ARGV[1] || "pcap-000"
pc = Pcap.open_offline(ARGV[0])
pc.each do |pk|
  fn1 = fn.succ!
  File.binwrite(fn1, pk)
end
```